# Advanced Reporting Cron Failing

Tags: magento2.3, magento-cron, advanced-reporting

I'm getting an error in my Magento 2.3.6 when I run `n98-magerun2 sys:cron:run analytics_collect_data` and overnight in the cron table.

```
Run Magento\Analytics\Cron\CollectData::execute
Cron-job "analytics_collect_data" threw exception Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException

In File.php line 226:
Directory "/tmp/analytics/tmp" cannot be created Warning!mkdir(): Permission denied
```

In my development environment I've set the var folder to permissions 777 and manually created the `tmp/analytics/tmp` folder all with permissions set to 777 but I still get the error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check the group and owner settings in the permission for that folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run these commands to make it work:

```
mkdir pub/media/analytics
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
sudo find var pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;
sudo find var pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;
sudo chmod u+x bin/magento
```

The system is trying to get the folder from `/tmp/` as a fallback, it's not the folder expected.